# Java fizzBuzz (excercise from CodingBat- Array2)

Tags: java, fizzbuzz

I have this fizzBuzz excercise from codingBat https://codingbat.com/prob/p153059 , my idea of solving is pretty basic:

```
public String[] fizzBuzz(int start, int end) {
  
  int n=end-start;
  
  String[] array=new String[n];
  
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    
    if(((start+i) % 3 ==0) && ((start+i) % 5 ==0)) array[i]="FizzBuzz";
    if((start+i) % 5 ==0)  array[i]="Buzz";
    if((start+i) % 3 ==0)  array[i]="Fizz";
    
    
    else{
      array[i]=String.valueOf((start+i));
    }
  }
  
  return array;
  
}
```

I don't understand why at the if's part in the for loop only the bottom if is read so for example all numbers that are multiple of 3's as shown above will be displayed as "Fizz" but only them, then if i put a different if at the bottom, it will be the only one that is displayed, i can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You are using only if statement which will check all the conditions, and if last condition(bottom if) is satisfied then it will print its output.

So, U will have to use if...else statement for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now it makes sense why it printed only the bottom :)